# Node WPAPI REST with JWT Authentication combined?

Tags: wordpress, rest, jwt, wp-api

I have a Wordpress REST-API Backend with a UI5 JavaScript Frontend which loads some Post-Data to list them.

I want to protect this by a simple Login-Form in the Frontend.

To fetch and create the posts i use [Node-WPAPI](http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/using-the-client/) with basic authencation, like this:

```
this._oWp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'http://<domain>/wordpress/wp-json',
    username: '<user>',
    password: '<pass>'
});
```

But this approach dont fit my needs, because creating this WPAPI instance is even possible with a wrog password. Thus i would have to send a request to protected route first to know if my password was correct.

To directly know if my login was correct my idea was to firstly get a Token via "JWT Authentication for WP-API" and this actually works and i get the token.

But doing this my WPAPI Endpoints resulting with error **"jwt_auth_bad_auth_header, "Authorization header malformed."**

Is there a way to use WPAPI together with JWT Auth? Or how could a Login be authenticated by WPAPI Instance and get directly notified when the login credential were wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this with the WPAPI-Only-Approach, so proving that the user entered the right credentials by simply sending a request to .users().me() which needs a correct authentification. Otherwise you get an "Not authenticated" Error.

```
let oWp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: <your_endpoint>,
    username: this._oAuth.getProperty("/Username"),
    password: this._oAuth.getProperty("/Password"),
});

oWp.users().me()
.then( user => {
    this._oWp.setData(oWp);
    this._oRouter.navTo('home');
}).catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```